# Personalized web parts summary links

Tags: web-part

I would need to have a personalized summary links web part in a given page. 
So when a user logs into the site, he should see his own links as opposed to system wide links inside the links web part.

Is it possible to have a personalized summary links web part?
How would that work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Summary Links Web Part seems to have fallen by the wayside with SharePoint 2010. But there is nothing stopping you creating a Links list and adding a list view web part. I think you can then modify the view to show only the links associated with the current user.